# How can you change text color in Perl?

Tags: perl, colors

I need to find a simple way to change the color of output text in Perl. How do I do it?

```perl
print "Do you agree with me that I'm a Perl noob?";
print "> ";
chomp(my $question = <STDIN>);
if($question eq "yes") {
  print "You are smart!";
} if($question eq "no") {
  print "You stupid";
}
```

I just want to change the color. Nothing else to say.

Comment: It depends on the terminal. For most unixy terminals, try [Term::ANSIColor](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ANSIColor).

Comment: `print "You are \e[1;31msmart!\e[m\n"`

Comment: If you embed ANSI sequences in your output and the output goes to anything but an ANSI-compatible terminal, or a file, you'll see a bunch of ugly escape sequences.  I.e., you have to know what terminal device (or nowadays terminal device emulator) the output is destined for and adjust according to what it supports and expects for color information.

Answer (score 4):

Windows part untested:

```
use if 'MSWin32' eq $^O, 'Win32::Console::ANSI';
use Term::ANSIColor qw(:constants);

print BRIGHT_RED ON_BLUE "You are smart!\n";
print BOLD GREEN ON_WHITE "You stupid\n";

END { print RESET; }
```

If the terminal gets messed up because the `END` block was not run (e.g. due to a crash), run the `reset` command from `ncurses-utils` package.

Unfortunately [Term::ANSIColor](http://p3rl.org/Term::ANSIColor) does not support arbitrary colours because the API is stuck in the last millenium. You need to speak raw ANSI codes.

```
for my $c (split //, 'Sunshine, lollipops and rainbows') {
    printf "\x1b[38;2;%d;%d;%dm", rand 256, rand 256, rand 256; # fg
    printf "\x1b[48;2;%d;%d;%dm", rand 256, rand 256, rand 256; # bg
    print $c;
}
END { print "\x1b[0m"; } # reset
```